# ¿Como se puede lanzar un servicio desde un fragment y detenerlo desde el mismo fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-intent, android-service

Estoy intentando lanzar un servicio desde un fragment pero a la hora de enlazar un intent no me acepta el comando startService(intent), por lo que he probado si lo lanzo desde una actividad si que me lo acepta debido a que coge características AppCompatActivity y posee context propio. El error me aparece cuando en un fragment intento lanzar el servicio con un botón.

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(), ServiceToast.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        btnservic2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(), ServiceToast.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo respondio el usuario Vickas.

Con lo siguiente:

In Fragment Start your service using

getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceToast.class))